# Prove that spinors satisfying the Killing equation lives on a sphere

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, spinors

Considering that the covariant derivative $D_{\mu}$ acting on spinors be given by

$$D_{\mu} \eta = \pm \frac{i}{2} \gamma_{\mu} \eta$$

It is claimed that theses spinors lives on a constant curvature spacetime. In fact, a sphere.  I was trying to show it, simply by analysing the commutator

$$[D_{\mu},D_{\nu}] \eta =\frac{1}{4} [ \gamma_{v}, \gamma_{\mu}] \eta$$

So basically the Riemman tensor is ($a,b$ are flat indices, $\mu \nu$ are general indices)

$$R_{\mu \nu b}^a = \frac{1}{4} [\gamma_v,\gamma_{\mu}]^a_b$$

So, to obtain the Ricci scalar/curvature, we should do the following

$$R = R^a_{\mu v b} (e^{-1})^{\mu}_a (e^{-1})^v_b$$

Where $e$ are vielbein. The problem is that i don't know how to proceed here! I mean, i only know some properties of vielbein, like $e^a_{\mu} e^{\mu}_b = \delta^a_b$, or its definition itself (using general and flat metric), but i don't think this help here.

Look, since $R^a_{\mu v b}$ is contant, i already know the spacsetime has a cosntant curvature. I should only derive now that the ricci scalar is positive.